# Insert Rows At Index Path Crashes But Not Reload Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm facing a weird problem.

I have an array of string and a tableview controller. When I add data to my string array and use insert row method to update my table view, my app crashes.

This is my array:

```
var stringArray = ["A","D"]
```

and this is my insert rows method:

```
let additionItems = ["B","C"]
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
stringArray.insert(contentsOf: additionItems, at: 0)
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

The thing is, if I use:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

I don't receive any crashes and my tableView gets updated accordingly. Can anyone please explain the problem with my code?

Comment: Can you confirm that `stringArray.insert(contentsOf: additionItems, at: 0)` is inserting both "B" and "C" which changes the length/count of the array to 4? You're probably getting an index out of bounds error. It would help if posted the error you get when it crashes.

Comment: Index is not out of bounds and my stringArray gets updated without a problem

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving when using your initial method? I am assuming it has something to do with `begin` and `end` updates.

Comment: make your tableview editable first. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614876-setediting

Comment: Do those B and C are not getting added ? or you are asking why app crashes if you do not make use of **tableView.reloadData()** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to `stringArray.insert...` to be after the call to `beginUpdates`. The problem with having it before is that `beginUpdates` thinks the data model is already update to date but the table hasn't been told about the update yet.

Another option is to remove the calls to `begin/endUpdates`. They are not needed in this case.

In addition to making one of those changes, you also have to realize that you are adding two values to your data model but you are only telling the table view that you are inserting one row. You need an index path for both rows and insert both to match the two objects added to the array.

Since you wish to insert the two new rows between the two existing rows, you need:

```
let additionItems = ["B","C"]
let indexPathB = IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)
let indexPathC = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
stringArray.insert(contentsOf: additionItems, at: 1)
tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPathB, indexPathC], with: .automatic)
```

Note the change in index when inserting the items into `stringArray` and the need for two corresponding index paths.

Comment: I remove begin/endUpdates but the problem still exists so I think in order to insert more than 1 row, I have to use tableView.reloadData(), am I correct?

Comment: Did you read my whole answer? The last (3rd) paragraph is important.

Comment: Can you give me a code sample for an index path for both rows? My intention is to add B and C in between A and D

Comment: If my additionItems is dynamic where sometimes it can be 4 more/less items. What do you think is the best way to handle it? Should I use reloadData() instead of insertRow? I want insert row because I want to have animation.

Comment: If you want the animation, you can't use `reloadData`. Just use a loop to create an array of index paths and pass that array to the call to `insertRows`.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think an IndexPath for each new item is needed. Have you tried:

```
let paths = [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)]
tableView.insertRows(at: paths, with: .automatic)
```